# How can I make a histogram in rbokeh?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rbokeh

I am trying to generate a histogram in rbokeh.

The direct approach `ly_hist` leads to an unexpected counts (fig below, top). The indirect approach `ly_bar` gives a x-axis that is not sorted by factor level (fig below, bottom).

`rbokeh`

[image]

`ggplot2` gives the expected results.

[image]

code:

```
library(data.table)
library(rbokeh)
library(ggplot2)

# generate data ==============
set.seed(123)
x = data.table(
  hour = sample.int(n = 24, size = 100, replace = T)
)

# summarize
y = x[, .N, keyby = hour]

# ggplot ======================
theme_set(theme_bw())

g1 = ggplot(x) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(hour), bins = 24, fill = "steelblue", col = "white", alpha = 0.5 ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 24, 1))

g2 = ggplot(y) + 
  geom_bar(aes(hour, N), stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue", alpha = 0.5)


# rbokeh ==================
b1 = figure() %>%
  ly_hist(hour, data = x, breaks = 24)

y[, hour := factor(hour)]

b2 = figure() %>%
  ly_bar(hour, N, data = y)
```

Q: (1) how can I generate a histogram using rbokeh that produces the expected result (as in ggplot2) and (2) how can I get the x-axis to be sorted in the right order?

Comment: What makes you think the rbokeh histogram is incorrect?

Comment: I meant the output is _unexpected_. I compared the plot with the "y" object (see code) and the ggplot result.

Comment: Well, your Q (1) is "how can I generate a correct histogram using rboken" which implies it was incorrect in the first place. In any case, you can play with the arguments to `ly_hist`, which are exactly the same as those to `hist`.

Comment: (Btw, this is why statisticians tend to favour kernel densities over histograms. There is nothing wrong with the ly_hist output, and illustrates that a histogram can be quite sensitive to the placement of bins. But everybody still uses histograms, including statisticians.)

Comment: I have tried that. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The `ly_hist` function treats the data as continuous and therefore bins it, so the output obtained for `ly_hist` should be expected.

For `ly_bar`, you can control the x axis by either specifying the `xlim` argument to `figure()`:

```
figure(xlim = as.character(1:24)) %>%
  ly_bar(hour, N, data = y)
```

or by piping the figure through the `x_range()` function:

```
figure() %>%
  ly_bar(hour, N, data = y) %>%
  x_range(as.character(1:24))
```

Also note that if you do not want to do the summarization up front, you can just pass the x variable and it will count things up.

```
figure(xlim = as.character(1:24)) %>%
  ly_bar(as.character(hour), data = x)
```

By default, ideally rbokeh should honor factor level ordering for axes and should be able to handle inputs of unexpected types more gracefully (to avoid the `as.character()` business), and these will be addressed in future updates.